# JMS-HornetQ JBoss AS6 configuration

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss6.x, hornetq

Sometimes getting below exception

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create a session: Unable to get managed connection for JmsXA
    at org.hornetq.ra.HornetQRASessionFactoryImpl.allocateConnection(HornetQRASessionFactoryImpl.java:881)
    at org.hornetq.ra.HornetQRASessionFactoryImpl.createQueueSession(HornetQRASessionFactoryImpl.java:237)
```

While creating QueueSession, below is the snippet used

```
connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

We are using java:JmsXA connection factory which uses INVM .
AFAIK there is no use of setting parameters in nettyconnectionfactory and INVMconnectionfactory in hornetq-jms.xml
Either we should set it some parameters in jms-ds.xml(JMS Queue Configuration File) or ra.xml(MDB configuration file)

I know some parameters can be set to
1. `<reconnect-attempts>1000</reconnect-attempts>`
this will try to reconnect 1000 times after it gets disconnected
2. `<call-timeout>10800000</call-timeout>`

also there is no use of setting 
 as it is default to -1 and will try to connect unlimited no. of times

I am confused as to what parameters can be set and at what level ..i.e. either on queue level (in jms-ds.xml) or at MDB level (ra.xml) as some parameters are same e.g. call-timeout,retry-interval,etc

Answer (score 0):

Try with increasing `max-pool-size` of pooled-connection-factory `JmsXA`.